# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd Replacing £ with?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

When I create a SQL Script that inserts the value '£' or '€' into a table the value on the table is a question mark (?)
Though, when I insert '$' it inserts a dollar sign.

Anyone know what is going on and how to make sure a pound sign is inserted into the table?

Comment: It's an effect caused by Brexit - the system is unsure if the British are going to remain in the EU or not!

Comment: What version of SQL, what database collation, please provide sample DDL and the PowerShell code you're using.

Comment: USE _DBA
GO

INSERT INTO DENNIS VALUES ('£')

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $TargetServerName -Database Master -InputFile $file.FullName -QueryTimeout 21600

Answer (score 1):

I managed to test that the text file may have been the issue. When I opened up the text file and changed the encoding to Unicode, the £ and the € were inserted into the databsase.